# How to rename a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, function, rename

How do we rename a jquery function. let's say i want to rename the Jquery UI function `draggble()` to `xdraggble()` so that it does not conflict with another draggable function loaded from another library. Does renaming affect performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this, executed *before* the other script loads:

```
jQuery.fn.xdraggable = jQuery.fn.draggable;
```

Comment: you may need to call `delete jQuery.fn.draggable` if the other script checks for the existence of `jQuery.fn.draggable`.

Comment: why would the other script check for the existence of draggable. What does delete do behind the scene.

Comment: @Pinkie: see the [MDC `delete` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator).

Comment: `delete` deletes the value of property in object but not the property itself

Answer (score 2):

```
var xdraggable = $.fn.draggable;
//or
var xdraggable = $.draggable;
```

(depending implementation)

Same as what you'd do if you wanted to override the function but still have access.

*See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original/296706#296706) regarding what I mean by overriding*

Comment: You set xdraggble as a var. I can't use it as a function.

Comment: @Pinkie: I was just demonstrating you can make it any variable and copy the function. MattBall's answer copies it within the jQuery object (which is more or less what you probably want--retain implementation, just use a different alias). Also, you can call xdraggable as a function, try this: `var a = function(){ alert('Hello, world!'); } a();`

Comment: +1 @Brad: very insightful @ Pinkie: are functions not first class variables in javascript? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/705173/what-is-meant-by-first-class-object

Comment: @brad I set `var xdraggable = $.fn.draggable;`, when i try `$('div').xdraggble();` it doesn't work. Isn't this how i'm supposed to use it.

Comment: @Pinkie: use `jQuery.fn.xdraggable = jQuery.draggable` then try.

Comment: I got it, but `jQuery.draggable` does not work. It only works when it has the `fn` like `jQuery.fn.draggable` as i matts answer. +1 for the info.

Comment: @Pinkie: `jQuery.fn.` is the shortcut to `jQuery.prototype`. It extends the jQuery object so you can use `$(...).xdraggable`--but it needs to be a jquery object.