# How to override a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to override a built in `parseFloat` function in **JavaScript**.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: i wouldn't recommend doing that.  perhaps create another function within the prototype?

Comment: You could just do `function parseFloat() {}`, but there is as far as I know no way to actually call the native version then.

Comment: Overriding function is very common practice.

Comment: You would use composition. `const parseFloatOverride = () => parseFloat();`

Answer (score 268, accepted):

```
var origParseFloat = parseFloat;
parseFloat = function(str) {
     alert("And I'm in your floats!");
     return origParseFloat(str);
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to call the native version inside a custom `parseFloat`? I tried this but it errors 'Maximum call stack size exceeded': http://jsfiddle.net/huZG2/. Thanks.

Comment: @David Waters: I'm afraid your current code alerts forever in Chrome.

Comment: @David Keep in mind that function are hoisted, which mean that `origParseFloat` points to the function you declare right after. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/huZG2/2/) would work.

Comment: @HoLyVieR: Thanks, I see it's possible to both override and use the native `parseFloat`: http://jsfiddle.net/huZG2/3/.

Comment: @HoLyVieR thanks Fixed by assigning function to name  answer updated see http://jsfiddle.net/huZG2/6/

Comment: If you want to keep the original function anonymous and be able to use it only in your overriding, you can see another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original

Comment: This is not a function override. Overrides do not alter the original function. This is an overwrite.

Answer (score 48):

You can override any built-in function by just re-declaring it.

```
parseFloat = function(a){
  alert(a)
};
```

Now `parseFloat(3)` will alert 3.

Comment: But there is no concept of function overriding in this answer, i.e. overriding functionality but keeping the function name same.

Comment: This is not a function override, this is a complete overwrite.

Answer (score 41):

You could override it or preferably **extend** it's implementation like this

```
parseFloat = (function(_super) {
    return function() {
        // Extend it to log the value for example that is passed
        console.log(arguments[0]);
        // Or override it by always subtracting 1 for example
        arguments[0] = arguments[0] - 1;
        return _super.apply(this, arguments);
    };         

})(parseFloat);
```

And call it as you would normally call it:

```
var result = parseFloat(1.345); // It should log the value 1.345 but get the value 0.345
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like this:

```
alert(parseFloat("1.1531531414")); // alerts the float
parseFloat = function(input) { return 1; };
alert(parseFloat("1.1531531414")); // alerts '1'
```

Check out a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LtjzW/1/

Answer (score 8):

#### An override is a concept that comes from object-oriented programming, where inheritance is used to extend class methods

Javascript has classes (and prototype inheritance), but `parseFloat` is simply a function and not a class (or a prototype). So you would either need to make `parseFloat` a class method, or override the related `Number.parseFloat` method.

Let's explore this further. An override method, does not mutate (extend or overwrite) the original parent method. As illustrated in the following example:

```js
class A {
  // parent method
  print() {
    console.log("class A");
  }
}

class B extends A {
  // override method
  print() {
    console.log("class B");
  }
  parentPrint() {
    super.print();
  }
}

const b = new B();
b.print(); // prints "class B" from override method
b.parentPrint(); // prints "class A" from parent method
```

To apply this to `Number.parseFloat`, we could do:

```js
class B extends Number {
  // overrides `parseFloat` from Number class
  parseFloat() {
    super.parseFloat();
  }
}

const b = new B();
b.parseFloat();
```

#### However, modern practice is to favor composition over object-oriented inheritance.

Inheritance is regarded as confusing, fragile, and less flexible when compared to composition. React (Facebook) and Go (Google) programming languages for example, both encourage composition:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance
- https://go.dev/doc/faq#inheritance
- https://go.dev/doc/faq#overloading

Therefore my basic recommendation is to use composition:

```js
const parseFloatOverride = function () {
  return parseFloat();
};
```

And my extended recommendation is use composition with dependency injection, to create loosely coupled dependencies which are more suitable for unit testing.

```js
// Inject the `Number` dependency
const parseFloatOverride = function (Number number) {
  return number.parseFloat();
};
```

#### Warning: do not overwrite the Javascript core library

Also almost every answer on this thread overwrites the `parseFloat` function. That's bad practice, because (a) developers expect `parseFloat` to work as documented, and (b) that includes developers who wrote any third-party packages you might use, that would now be corrupted. So do not overwrite the Javascript core library, and instead use composition or inheritance.

```
const parseFloat = function () {}; // Bad practice
const Number.prototype.parseFloat = function () {}; // Also bad practice
```

Comment: "Inheritance is regarded as confusing, fragile, and less flexible when compared to composition" reputable citations needed, not just links to posts by people who are commenting either about _when using React_ (which has a completely different approach to both data management and event handling) or even a completely different programming language. JS Inheritance is not confusing _if you use JS itself_ rather than some framework that has its own bespoke conventions but happens to be built using JS.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - The documentation here for Golang was written by Russ Cox about 3 years ago (https://github.com/golang/website/blame/50957a7e9e705605066784e977c4d4885ed638f5/_content/doc/faq.html#L728), and for React by Nat Alison (https://github.com/reactjs/legacy.reactjs.org/blame/17c317114bfc4ca59a4d6450a384efde8b7ed817/content/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.md#L172) about 5 years ago. If you do not consider these authors reputable or disagree that composition is better, then use inheritance.

Comment: As useful as their opinions are, that's all they are. Opinions, based on not needing JS. Go has a completely different foundation, and React explicitly started as "what if we don't JS, but on top of JS anyway". Neither of them are authoritative with respect to, or proper commentaries on, JS itself, they're only useful in the context of "if you want to do this other thing". And then, yeah. JS inheritance could very well be confusing because the thing you're trying to learn doesn't, or tries very hard, not to use it.