# Overriding/Extending the Magento core javascript files

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.6

Last days as a result of some customer complains and discussion with our marketing guys I've got a request to change the default behavior of the configurable products options. They asked me to remove the + $xx.xx from the options drop-down as it is confusing the customers/visitors and just leave the available options without displaying the price change. Fair enough from their point of view, but it is a bit tricky from developers point of view I think. The site is running Magento CE 1.6.2, and the file which we need to override/change is /public_html/js/varien/configurable.js. We need to change the getOptionLabel function in it so that it does not display the price change.
So my question is: what is the right Magento way to change this file and not touch the core javascript file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: javascript dont suport overrides.
but see that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409428/how-to-override-a-javascript-function

Comment: @Guerra are you sure prototype has a way to wrap() things nicely

Comment: IMO this is a hack to simulate OOP overrides, but work's fine

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See this from prototype manual http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/language/Function/prototype/wrap/ you can wrap whatever object method and even call "parent" if needed and here's a pseudo sample:

```
//where Product.Config is the object/class you need to "override"
Product.Config.prototype.getOptionLabel  = Product.Config.prototype.getOptionLabel.wrap(function(parentMethod){
    //replace the original method here with your own stuff
    //or call parentMethod(); if conditions don't match
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anton for your hint. I will play with it in the morning and see how it performs.

Comment: For Magento 1.7 this works: Product.Config.prototype.getOptionLabel = Product.Config.prototype.getOptionLabel.wrap

Comment: guess it depends how methods are named

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where the best place would be to place the JS file that overrides the core file.  In my case, it's js/prototype/validation.js, and I see probably 5 to 10 different references to that .js file throughout Mage.  And not all of them are layout xml.

Comment: you can add to whatever file loaded after the original file. I'd add my own file and place it there.

Comment: this has nothing to do with 1.9.2.1 but features on prototypejs library

Answer (score 26):

Just to add to @anton-s's absolutely correct answer, you can also do "full" class rewrites:

```
// Create the original class
var ClassA = Class.create();
ClassA.prototype = {
    initialize: function(config) {
        this.config = config;
    },
    test: function(msg) {
        console.log('Hi from class A with message ' + msg);
    }
};

// Create new class extending the original class
var ClassB = Class.create(ClassA, {
    // $super is a reference to the original method
    test: function($super, msg) {
        console.log('Hi from class B');
        console.log('this.config is accessible in class B: ' + this.config);
        $super(msg + ' ...')
    }
});


// To make the extend an override, you can do this:
ClassA = ClassB;
// ClassA now is ClassB overriding the original ClassA
var a = new ClassA('some config data');
a.test('Call A 1');
```

Since all this only works on prototype classes, not on already instantiated objects, I'll also throw in this hack, which is pretty much what wrap() does, too:

```
// Overriding a method of an already instantiated object
// There are many ways to do this more elegantly thanks to the amazing JS scoping magic
a.origTest = a.test;
a.test = function(msg) {
    console.log('Hi from the patched method');
    this.origTest(msg);
}
a.test('Call A 2');
```

Keep in mind though that the `wrap()` method is nicer, and can also be used on on class definitions or on concrete instances.

```
// Wrap method of concrete instance
spConfig.getOptionLabel = spConfig.getOptionLabel.wrap(function(parentMethod, option, price) {
    return parentMethod(option, price);
});

// Wrap method of class declaration
Product.Config.prototype.getOptionLabel = Product.Config.prototype.getOptionLabel.wrap(function(parentMethod, option, price) {
    return parentMethod(option, price);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vinai and Anton S for your valuable hints. We've changed our temporary js hack and now it is done in the right Magento way. You're rocks!

Comment: @MilenPetrov accept the answer that helps you out to improve the SO experience for others who search the similar

Comment: @Anton S - Really sorry that i forgot to do that

Answer (score 0):

**How to override \js\varien\configurable.js in Magento 1.9 EE and add new data attribute**

Create file \js\jsoverride\configurable.js:

```
    Product.Config.prototype.reloadOptionLabels = Product.Config.prototype.reloadOptionLabels.wrap(function (parentMethod, element) {
    var selectedPrice;
    if (element.options[element.selectedIndex].config && !this.config.stablePrices) {
        selectedPrice = parseFloat(element.options[element.selectedIndex].config.price);
    } else {
        selectedPrice = 0;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < element.options.length; i++) {
        if (element.options[i].config) {
            element.options[i].text = this.getOptionLabel(element.options[i].config, element.options[i].config.price - selectedPrice);
            element.options[i].setAttribute('data-in-stock', element.options[i].config.in_stock);
        }
    }
});
```

Create or use file: \app\design\frontend\enterprise\YOUR_THEME\layout\local.xml and add next rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>jsoverride/configurable.js</script></action>
    </reference>
  </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Note, filling data to element.options[i].config.in_stock in file

> app\design\frontend\enterprise\YOUR_THEME\template\catalog\product\view\type\options\configurable.phtml

with next row

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(UPDATED JSON WITH NEW ATTRIBUTE);
```