# Change event function parameters with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an image map that contains certain "Areas" that contain onmouseover events. Most of these events fire a function which passes in some coordinates. 
I want to be able to manipulate the coords in the function SFX_ShowIconOver.

The Image Map is created by a third party app so I can only manipulate rendered content.

```
<AREA onmouseover="SFX_ShowIconOver('Chart2','29456',368,10,22,22,false,this)" title="Legend Box" onclick="SFX_SendCommand('29456',false)" shape=rect coords=368,10,390,32>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use inline javascript, change to the jQuery style, then change the variables `a,b,c,d,e`.

```
var a,b,c,d,e;
$('#area_id').mouseover(function() {
   SFX_ShowIconOver('Chart2', a, b, c, d, e, false,this);
}).click(function() {
   SFX_SendCommand(a, false);
});
```

Comment: The function is created on the fly by a third party app. So I need some way of being able to locate this function "SFX_ShowIconOver" and manipulate its content. In fact the whole image map is created by a third party app.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery to remove the `onmouseover` attributes from the DOM and then just add your own mouseovers using JQuery.

**EDIT**
have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409428/how-to-override-a-javascript-function). then all you would need to do is make sure that your 'overridden' function is declared after the 3rd party item is loaded.

Comment: It's only the fourth parameter I want to change. Do you know how I would do this?

Comment: @hoakey see my edit. you shouldn't need to do anything with JQuery in my edit. you are just overridding the JS function.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve what I wanted in the end. Here's the code:

```
            $("area").filter(function () { return this.outerHTML.match('SFX_ShowIconOver') })
        .each(function () {
            var pairs = $(this).attr("outerHTML").split(', ');

            for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
                var nums = pairs[i].split(',');
                nums[3] = 40;
                pairs[i] = nums.join(',');
            }

            $(this).attr("outerHTML", pairs.join(', '));
        });
```