# Access variable from 1 .js source file (jqTree), from within different .js file, to override method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqtree

(new to JS, jQuery, & jqTree)

**I am trying to override a method** (`JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode`) **from one .js file** ([tree.jquery.js](https://rawgit.com/mbraak/jqTree/master/tree.jquery.js)) **in another** (my own `custom.js`).

I've read that [to override a js method in general, I just need to redefine it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409469/1357094).  So I am trying to do that on the method, and ***I think I am stuck on accessing the variable that has the original method*** (`JqTreeWidget`).  I think the challenge is that the original method is in `tree.jquery.js` (source) that is separate from my own other `custom.js` file where I want to do the override.

The goal of this Question would be to allow me to write [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1740510/1357094) in my `custom.js` (`<reference to JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode>` *would be the Answer to this Question*):

```
var originalMethod = <reference to JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode>;

// Override of originalMethod
<reference to JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode> = function( node, slide ){
    // my code I want to happen 1st here
    changeAncestorHeightRecursively( node, true);

    // my code is done, and now I'm ready to call the original method
    originalMethod.call( this, node, slide );
}
```

I think that would be the most non-intrusive way to do the override, without actually hacking in to the `tree.jquery.js` source.

**See my `custom.js` at http://codepen.io/cellepo/pen/LGoaQx**
The separate source `tree.jquery.js` is added externally in the JS settings of that codepen.

**How can I get access (from within my `custom.js` file) to `JqTreeWidget` variable that is in the source file (`tree.jquery.js`)?**  Is it even possible?  Is `JqTreeWidget` not in scope outside of `tree.jquery.js`, or is it not a global variable?  I was hoping `treeContainer.tree.prototype` would have it, but I haven't had luck so far...

Thanks!

Comment: CodePen from above, [forked & updated with Accepted Answer here](http://codepen.io/cellepo/pen/zrQXKZ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototype object can be obtained via:

```
jQuery.fn.tree("get_widget_class").prototype
```

Note that this is not a generalized solution for any jQuery plugin. This is something explicitly implemented by the tree plugin.

Comment: Looks like this indeed gets the prototype object, thanks!

Comment: Note that the parameter "get_widget_class" is not intended to be replaced:  Literally leave that in, and use the code in this Answer verbatim as-is.  (I was confused at first thinking I needed to replace it with a CSS selector for my tree, which is not the case)

Comment: Just curious:  Mind explaining how ".fn.tree("get_widget_class")" works?  Or do you have any API references for those methods? thanks

Comment: `jQuery.fn` is where all jQuery plugins register their functions. It is basically the prototype of all jQuery objects. The rest was seen by reading the `tree.jquery.js` file. I am not aware of it being documented anywhere.

Comment: Cool thanks.  I'm guessing after learning all this that you might have have narrowed in on the relevant part of tree.jquery.js by text searching it for "fn" or "$.fn". Nice

Comment: Same CodePen from question, [forked & updated with this solution](http://codepen.io/cellepo/pen/zrQXKZ)

Answer (score 0):

I found this hacky workaround.  But since it's a hack, I'd still prefer to find the Answer as posed in this Question (so **please, continue to Answer with respect to the `<reference to JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode>` I mentioned in the Question**, thanks)...

As stated in this Question, the goal involves making it possible to override `JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode` (from `tree.jquery.js`) externally in `custom.js`.  As such, calls to `changeAncestorHeightRecursively` (my code) & `JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode` would both be made from the override in `custom.js`, and `tree.jquery.js` source is not modified at all.

**Workaround:**

1. *[Declare global var in html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2932788/1357094)*:

   `<script type='text/javascript' language="javascript">
   changeAncestorHeightRecursively = 1;
    </script>`
2. In `custom.js`, *set the globar var to the function* (the one I want to be called before `JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode`):

   `window.changeAncestorHeightRecursively = changeAncestorHeightRecursively;`
3. *Call the global-var-referenced function at the beginning of `JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode`* (hack into `tree.jquery.js`):

   `JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode = function(node, slide) {
     // Only way I could figure out to get this to execute before the rest of this method
     // (global-var-referenced function in custom.js)
     changeAncestorHeightRecursively( node, true );`
     
     `// Rest of original openNode code...
   }`

*This calls my code function from within `tree.jquery.js`, as opposed to calling the overridden method from within `custom.js`.*  **So this is hacky because of the global var, and modifying `tree.jquery.js` source.**

This will work for now, but hoping for a less hacky Solution as stated in this original Question...  Thanks!

Comment: FWIW:  This theoreticially has risks changeAncestorHeightRecursively being called before it is defined (as my custom.js is loaded last).  But in reality, JqTreeWidget.prototype.openNode is only called upon user inupt.  So the by the time that input happens, all js would be loaded since the user has to see the loaded page before inputting on it :)