# Javascript: Overwrite a new function using the old function with same name

Tags: javascript, recursion, overwrite

For any function, for example:

```
function my_function(arg){
    switch(arg){
        case 1: return 100;
        case 2: return 150;
        case 3: return 300;
    }
}
```

I want to add a new `case 4: 500` into the function, so it should work like:

```
function my_function(arg){
    switch(arg){
        case 1: return 100;
        case 2: return 150;
        case 3: return 300;
        case 4: return 500;
    }
}
```

But I don't want overwrite the function with the same script again. So I tried this way:

```
function my_function(arg){
    switch(arg){
        case 4: 500;
        default: my_function(arg);
    }
}
```

But when I call other cases `1` `2` `3`, the function keeps calling itself. (I understand why it happens)

Is there a way to fix this?

More generally, is there a way to overwrite a function so the new function can use the old function?

P.S. I don't want to create a function with different names that copies the old function.

Comment: Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346503/what-is-the-opposite-of-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to create a function with the same name instead of updating the old function? And if you cannot update it, why not just name it differently as it's conceptually a separate one anyway?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409468/12944233.

Comment: but you need a reference to the old function.