# jQuery Mobile swipe events not fire when using scrollview plugin

Tags: jquery-mobile, scrollview, swipe

I use swipe events to change pages when swiping, that worked fine until using ScrollView plugin. I saw the help from [jQuery Mobile: scrollview and swipe events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736926/jquery-mobile-scrollview-and-swipe-events) but I don't know how to implement it now.
Any code snippets for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-scrollview/source/browse/trunk/sample.html?r=3

Answer (score 0):

You just need to comment out `e.stopPropagation()` in `_handleDragStart function()` to stop bubbling the parent events, like the JQM swipe events in your case.

OR you can disable according to condition, e.g., for vertical scrollbars, if you want to have `swipeLeft` and `swipeRight` events, use this

```
( this.options.direction == "y" ) ? "" : e.stopPropagation();
```

this should work.