# Is there a way to call a function every time a jquery basic function is called?

Tags: jquery

I would like everytime I call a jquery load function:

```
$("#div").load("file.php");
```

To then call a separate function:

```
function secondFunction() {
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original

Comment: Do you want it for `load`function only or are you asking for a more general answer?  the `load` function has a callback parameter.

Comment: I want it to be separate from the place where i call the load. So i need something that almost checks to see if there is a load and then calls it every time the something is loaded. @gdoron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as the callback:

```
$("#div").load("file.php", secondFunction);
```

Comment: @Ian34: When exactly do you want it to run?  There's no event that's triggered when `load` is called, or something like that.  What's wrong with using the callback function?

Answer (score 1):

if i have understood clearly you can call the second function as the call back each time `load` is called

```
$("#div").load("file.php",secondFunction);
```