# Can additional functionality be binded to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a function like this:

```
 function showAlert() {
   alert("1");
 }
```

Is there a way to bind additional functionality to the same function in a different part of the page?

Like this:

```
 function showAlert() {
   alert("1");
   alert("2");
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That would make the code impossible to read!

Comment: Additional functionality to the same function, like a `close modal` function. Instead of binding to the same element that calls the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overwrite the function with a new function that calls the old function.

```
 function showAlert() {
   alert("1");
 }

showAlert = (function (original){
 return function () {
   original();
   alert("2");
 }
}(showAlert));

showAlert();

​
```

Comment: ... and you even don't have to use `var showAlert = function()` for the first version, right. ) Nice one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply redefine the function:

```
function showAlert() {
    alert("1");
}

var originalShowAlert = showAlert;

showAlert = function(){
    originalShowAlert();
    alert("2");
}

showAlert();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since functions are treated simply as objects in JS, you can maintain an array of functions, then execute each function in a loop. This allows you to add any type of function that you want to the collection (and even remove them later if you keep the index), without breaking the execution train.

```
var funk = [];

funk.push(function showAlert1()
{
    alert("1");
});

funk.push(function showAlert2()
{

    alert("2");
});


funk.push(function showAlertFromMsg()
{
    alert("You passed " + this);

});


for(var i=0,len=funk.length; i<len; i++) funk[i].call("This is my message");
```