# How to store original window.onscroll function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have following code in my JavaScript library. My goal is to store the original `onscroll` function which is the first line of code snippet, and then point `onscroll` to a new function. However, what I am finding is that `wind.origonscroll` which is supposed to be the original scroll function is always pointing to the new function in second line.

**Question**: Is there a way to store the original function in code below, so `window.origscroll` always points to the function in first line of commented code? *I am trying to keep track of what was the original window's onscroll event, which is not related to overriding a function. I do not need to override a function here.*

```
 //window.onscroll = function() {console.log('scrolling done');}
 wind.origonscroll = window.onscroll;
 window.onscroll = function () { window.scrollTo(wind.x, wind.y); };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding a JavaScript function while referencing the original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original)

Comment: I am not trying to override a function. the post you mentioned is talking about how to override a function. What I am trying to do is store the original function that the window's onscroll event points to.

Comment: Could you please add a code reproducing your issue, your basic idea [seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/ktoq3hv2/1/).

Comment: @Teemu, you mean demo code on Fiddle or similar?

Comment: Just a bit of code with which we can reproduce your issue. A couple of additional lines to the post. A fiddle would be a nice extra, but not necessary.

Comment: `I am finding is that wind.origonscroll which is the original scroll function is always pointing to the new function in second line` - you're doing something wrong **somewhere else** (like maybe that piece of code gets executed twice

Comment: @Teemu, I have added an extra line to the code to show that there was an original function for window.onscroll, which should be stored in `wind.origonscroll`.

Comment: window.onscroll on load is null (aka there is not a handler defined). What do you mean when you say you want to keep track of the event? The event is the signal that fires when scroll happens, here we are talking about the handler function

Comment: I mean the handler function. Couldn't the handler for window.onscroll be already defined by the developer in some code? O are you saying that I should always consider window.onscroll as null for the original window.onscroll handler?

Comment: @Sunil Storing `window.onscroll` works fine, as you can see at my above linked fiddle. As Jaromanda X said, there must be something else in your code ...

Comment: @Teemu, I cannot see a link to a demo on fiddle. May be you forgot to post it.

Comment: @Teemu, I have the answer, so its ok. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sunil ??? The words "seems to work fine" in the  third comment on this thread is the link.

Comment: @Teemu, Thanks. Yes, I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If window.onscroll is not null  ( if has been defined before) it can be saved away.

Try this:

```
window.onscroll=function() { console.log('asd') }
var old = window.onscroll
window.onscroll=function() { console.log('gggg') }
old()
```