# Overriding JSON.stringify causing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, object

I just created a function that return JSON.stringify like this:

```
JSON.stringify = function (item, replacer, space) {
     return JSON.stringify(item, replacer, space);
}
```

and it causes all these errors on angularjs:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmSoy.jpg)

The reason I want to override the function is because I want to create a property in objects that tells the JSON to ignore a field, like this:

```
JSON.stringify = function (item, replacer, space) {
    if (angular.isObject(item)) {
        var newItem = angular.copy(item);
        var ignores = item.jsonIgnore || [];

        ignores.forEach(prop => {
            delete newItem[prop];
        });

        return JSON.stringify(newItem, replacer, space);
    }

    return JSON.stringify(item, replacer, space);
}
```

Comment: the function calls itself!

Comment: uhmm, I thought that it was calling the original JSON.stringify

Comment: Thanks dude, I resolved creating a local `var originalStringify = JSON.stringify;` and then calling `return originalStringify(item, replacer, space);`

Comment: @EduardoRosostolato You should post that [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I resolved creating a local variable with the original function

```
var originalStringify = JSON.stringify;
```

and then calling on my custom function

```
return originalStringify(item, replacer, space);
```

Now my full Json ignore override function is like this:

```
// JSON ignore
var original = JSON.stringify;

JSON.stringify = function (item, replacer, space) {
    if (angular.isObject(item)) {
        var newItem = angular.copy(item);
        var ignores = item.jsonIgnore || [];

        ignores.forEach(prop => {
            delete newItem[prop];
            delete newItem.jsonIgnore;
        });

        return original(newItem, replacer, space);
    }

    return original(item, replacer, space);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a recursive function without any end condition. Either you can solve the problem with creating a local function:

```
var localStringify = function (item, replacer, space) {
    ...
}
```

Or override the original function considering the explanation given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296667/overriding-a-javascript-function-while-referencing-the-original).