# Overriding Json.stringify to use json-stringify-safe

Tags: json, overriding, stringify

I want to override JSON.stringify to use the json-stringify-safe module to avoid getting circular error.

Here is my code :

```
(function () {
    const getSerialize = require('json-stringify-safe');
    const stringifyCore = JSON.stringify;
    JSON.stringify = (obj, replacer, spaces, cycleReplacer) => {
        return stringifyCore.apply(this, [obj, getSerialize(replacer, cycleReplacer), spaces]);
    };
}());
```

I also tried :

```
const getSerialize = require('json-stringify-safe');

const stringifyCore = JSON.stringify;
JSON.stringify = function (obj, replacer, spaces, cycleReplacer) {
    return stringifyCore(obj, getSerialize(replacer, cycleReplacer), spaces);
};
```

I get an error :

> Maximum call stack size exceeded

The solution eplanied here does not work for me..
[Overriding JSON.stringify causing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732104/overriding-json-stringify-causing-error)

Any ideas?

Comment: You probably don't want to use arrow functions if you need to use `this`.

Comment: in my second code, I'm not using arrow function and not even this

Comment: What is the goal of this implementation? I'm looking at the [readme](https://github.com/moll/json-stringify-safe) and it looks like it should be a drop in replacement. Looks like you're trying to do something else.

Comment: You probably meant to call the `getSerialize` function from the function. Perhaps you need to do `const {getSerialize} = require(...);`

Comment: The goal of this implementation is to continue using JSON.stringify in my application, instead of changing all references to the stringify function from json-stringify-safe module

Comment: The uses of const {getSerialize} = require(...); fixed the issue. But now I have another error.. it looks like it's not replacing the original stringify function... I get the 'Converting Circular structure to JSON' error. 
Is this applying on all my application or just in my actual file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooh Just figured out that I was not int the right file.. I was trying this on webpack.config.js (This is an AngularJS project). I moved it in my app.js file and it works.

Here is my solution in App.js

```
(function () {
    const {getSerialize} = require('json-stringify-safe');
    
    const stringifyCore = JSON.stringify;
    JSON.stringify = function (obj, replacer, spaces, cycleReplacer) {
        return stringifyCore(obj, getSerialize(replacer, cycleReplacer), spaces);
    };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is solved by changing the requires for getSerialize function to :

```
const {getSerialize} = require('json-stringify-safe');
```

Now, I have another problem, I want this to be applied in all my application, but it doesn't seems to work since I continue to get this error :

> Converting circular structure to Json

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
(function () {
    const {getSerialize} = require('json-stringify-safe');
    const _stringify = JSON.stringify;
    JSON.stringify = (obj, replacer, spaces, cycleReplacer) =>
        _stringify(obj, getSerialize(replacer, cycleReplacer), spaces);
}());
```

The point of the library is to use it instead of the base `JSON.stringify()` function. And judging by [the code](https://github.com/moll/json-stringify-safe/blob/master/stringify.js), it internally uses `JSON.stringify` already so we'll want to bypass that.